# Is set membership relation a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Relations in set theory are sets. But is the set membership relation, being a primitive term, a set too? How would it be defined as a set?

Comment: If the set of all sets exists (call it $U$), then the membership relation is the set $\{(x,y)\in U\times U\mid x\in y\}$. So if the set theory you work with allows for the constructions needed for this definition of a set, then you're done.

Answer (score 3):

It is not a set (e.g., in ZFC set theory) - it is "too big" to be one. In fact assume that there is a set $R$ such that the pair $(A,B)$ is $\in R$ iff $A\in B$. If we view ordered pairs the Kuratowski way, then $(A,B)$ is the set $\{\{A\},\{A,B\}\}$. For example $\emptyset\in\{\emptyset\}$ would then be represented by the fact
$$ \{\{\emptyset\},\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}\}\in R.$$
But then *this* relation would mean that
$$ \{ \{ \{\{\emptyset\},\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}\} \},\{ \{\{\emptyset\},\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}\},R\} \}\in R.$$
In effect, $R$ would appear somewhere deep inside an element of itself. This is close to Russel's paradox and the [Axiom of Foundation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity) has been introduced as kind of "guardian" against such paradoxes into ZFC.

Comment: So is the set membership relation a class? Or is it a set in those set theories that don't require that a set not be an element of itself?

Comment: @Tom in ZFC, the class of all $(A,B)$ where $A,B$ are sets with $A \in B$ is a proper class. For set theories without Foundation, it is upon them to decide this question